# Hide datatable row when total equals 0

Tags: laravel, datatable

```
->addColumn('name', function ($customer) {
            $d = '';
            if (request('due_filter')) {
                $sum = $customer->invoices->whereIn('status', array('due', 'partial'));
                $due = $sum->sum('total') - $sum->sum('pamnt');
                $d = '<span class="badge badge-danger">' . amountFormat($due) . '</span>';
            }
            return '<a class="font-weight-bold" href="' . route('biller.customers.show', [$customer->id]) . '">' . $customer->name . '</a>' . $d;
        })
```

[image]

How can I hide customer row if total equals 0.00?

Comment: hi you want to remove row or entity from table ?

Comment: if you want to remove row then you have to solve a query where total > 0

Comment: @WaleedMuaz how can get customer have invoice's status is due with query? now return all customer